# Failed Simple PHP Google App Engine Live Deployment

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I've got a PHP whitelisted account and created a simple helloworld app called afreekaworld with a...

## app.yaml file that looks like this

```
application: afreekaworld
```

version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /stylesheets
  static_dir: stylesheets

- url: /.*
  script: afreekaworld.php

## afreekaworld.php

(1) All my Uploads fail with errors - lots of checking and then ...

```
05:53 AM Checking if deployment succeeded.
2013-06-18 05:53:23,771 WARNING appcfg.py:1801 Version still not ready to serve,     aborting. 
013-06-18 05:53:23,771 ERROR appcfg.py:2049 An unexpected error occurred. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-    default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line     2030, in DoUpload
app_summary = self.Commit()
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-    default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line   1802, in Commit
raise Exception('Version not ready.')
Exception: Version not ready.
05:53 AM Rolling back the update.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/appcfg.py", line 171, in <module>
run_file(__file__, globals())
File "/usr/local/bin/appcfg.py", line 167, in run_file
execfile(script_path, globals_)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine- default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line  4247, in <module>
main(sys.argv)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine- default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line  4238, in main
result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2396, in Run
self.action(self)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 3973, in __call__
return method()
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2974, in Update
self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, self.basepath, appyaml, yaml_file_basename)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2923, in UpdateVersion
return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 2030, in DoUpload
app_summary = self.Commit()
File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py", line 1802, in Commit
raise Exception('Version not ready.')
Exception: Version not ready.
```

(2) Some other apps I've tried uploading, show errors logs in Admin - https://appengine.google.com/logs of instance urls in the log, but none have been created yet.

Is it possible that my whitelist provision is corrupt in someway, can someone for Google App engine please take a look :-), because I can't do anything usefull at the moment :-)

For instance - this is in our log for another app we tried to deploy to day...

```
2013-06-17 21:24:13.270 / 500 698ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0

46.65.177.73 - - [17/Jun/2013:21:24:13 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 406 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0" "afreekamobwp.appspot.com" ms=699 cpu_ms=454 cpm_usd=0.000045 loading_request=1 app_engine_release=1.8.1 instance=00c61b117c76a3a17827f8a385fb45c3a650

I 2013-06-17 21:24:13.270

This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
```

======================
Every time we try to access it from a browser, it generates another error warning message, but in fact the Admin console, does not have a single instance listed, and no deployments have ever completed successfully, they all fail - so where is this instance reference coming from? and how can it be fixed?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :-)

Ps: Just found some more in logs..where it claims the app has been deployed, but I like I mentioned before no instances are listed anywhere.

```
2013-06-17 22:54:59     apps-extensibility@google.com   Deleted builtin bundle     version: ah-builtin-datastoreservice.368168489818936938  
2013-06-17 22:48:52     apps-extensibility@google.com   Deleted builtin bundle   version: ah-builtin-datastoreservice.368168489818936938    
2013-06-17 22:48:24     apps-extensibility@google.com   Created builtin bundle version: ah-builtin-datastoreservice.368168489818936938
```

2013-06-17 22:45:36     myemail@gmail.com   Deployed a new version      version=1.2013-06-18T05:45:35Z
    2013-06-17 21:39:12     myemail@gmail.com   Deployed a new version   version=1.2013-06-18T04:39:11Z
    2013-06-17 21:35:24     myemail@gmail.com   Google APIs Console Project created
2013-06-17 21:35:20     myemail@gmail.com   Created the application

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that while your account has been whitelisted, this particular app had not been.  I've now set you up for this app, so give it another try.  Additional apps do need to be individually whitelisted-- you can register them here: https://gaeforphp.appspot.com/ .

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But I am still not having any joy. No instance, still "will check again in 60 seconds" message in Terminal window etc...also now I am not getting any logs either. I am now only testing afreekamob (helloworld style), I also posted an app afreekamobwp could you check on that too, or am I allowed only to run 1 app at a time?

Comment: Noticed in Admin ->Main->Versions,click on the version number,runs the app, but still not showing instances, terminal still running the message "Will check again in 60", and Admininstration->application settings->Application->identifier alias,  url errors - requested url cannot be found.

Comment: if I type http://1.afreekamob.application.com, but http://afreekamob.appspot.com does not work. So nothing else in the console seems to be displaying the right information. I'll leave it for a few hours to see if it will settle down, and check the admin console again. thanks

Comment: I have continued to try and set this up, and it is a bit frustrating without the console providing any feedback that tells me what is actually going on. Can someone please help, I still can't get my console to work properly. same errors as before, I see someone has tried working on it, but I have had no feedback as to what I can see how those new admin items help?

Comment: Afreeka, the app that's been whitelisted is the one indicated in your original query: 'afreekaworld'.